# Getting Forbidden Error Using SecurityFilterChain In SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

SecurityFilterChain does not work
I'm using Spring 2.7.8
Spring Security core -6.1.0
spring-security-config - 5.7.6
spring-security-web - 5.7.6

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final JWTAuthFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private final LogoutHandler logoutHandler;

    private static final String AUTH_END_POINT = "/auth/**";
    private static final String CATEGORY_ADMIN = "/categories/admin/**";
    private static final String ORDER_ADMIN = "/orders/admin/**";
    private static final String VENDOR_ADMIN = "/vendors/admin/**";
    private static final String PRODUCT_ADMIN = "/products/admin/**";
    private static final String USER_ADMIN = "/users/admin/**";
    private static final String ADMIN = "ADMIN";

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(@NotNull HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(AUTH_END_POINT).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/vendors/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/categories/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/products/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/users/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/orders/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(PRODUCT_ADMIN).hasAuthority(ADMIN)
                .antMatchers(VENDOR_ADMIN).hasAuthority(ADMIN)
                .antMatchers(USER_ADMIN).hasAuthority(ADMIN)
                .antMatchers(CATEGORY_ADMIN).hasAuthority(ADMIN)
                .antMatchers(ORDER_ADMIN).hasAuthority(ADMIN)
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/auth/logout")
                .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
                .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) ->
                        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext());

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Here's my JWTAuthFilter class.
doFilterInternal extracts credentials from jwt

```
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String userEmail;
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail = jwtTokenProvider.extractUsername(jwt);
        if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            var isTokenValid = tokenRepository.findByToken(jwt)
                    .map(t -> !t.isExpired() && !t.isRevoked())
                    .orElse(false);
            if (jwtTokenProvider.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails) && isTokenValid) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

GET `httpMethods` work with permitAll()
But endpoints with `hasRole(ADMIN)` do not work (I'm getting Forbidden)

Comment: You are mixing different versions of Spring Security, don't. Also `hasRole` will check if a user has an authority with the name `ROLE_ADMIN` if it is named `ADMIN` in your actual database it won't match.

Comment: i changed Spring Security versions to 5.7.6
and hasRole() to hasAuthority() 
having the same

Comment: Is your filter working correctly with extracting the credentials? Do you have additional security with `@PreAuthorize` or `@Secured` in place?

Comment: Yes, some methods have @PreAuthorize/
 Shouldn't it be like this?

Comment: And i deleted all @PreAuthorize 
Still having the same

Comment: Are those correct and matching? What makes you think the matchers here are the problem and not the pre-authorize ones? And as stated is your JWT filter working properly.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean) 
Maybe i can share my project on github?

Comment: Well does yuour jwt filte ractually extract the token properly and fill the security context, it appears as if it doesn't. I'm not going to debug your whole project (unless you hire me for consultancy) so just add the needed information here. You also have a custom authenticationprovider does that work as well.

Comment: im going to be a bit strict here and ask why havn't you enabled spring security debug logs, and read the reason for your Forbidden response, also why do you have a custom JWTFilter, and why are you not using the built in JWT features of spring security. Im suspecting you have followed some poor tutorial and when that didnt work you asked here. I suggest you read the official spring docs instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum i added my doFilterInternal method